# Tiling the plane with non-similar triangles with restictions

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, tiling, triangulation

Recently I stumbled upon this question [Similar Triangles in Tiling a Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629258/similar-triangles-in-tiling-a-plane), and I considered the same problem after imposing some restrictions. In particular I considered the following cases.

> 1. Find a triangular tiling of the plane where no triangle is similar to another one, and each triangle is **rational-sided**.

Sketch of the proof: we start by tiling the plane with $3-4-5$ right-triangles and then it is possible to split each right-triangle into two rational-sided triangles in infinitely many different ways.

> 2. Find a triangular tiling of the plane where no triangle is similar to another one, and each triangle is **integer-sided**.

Here I feel quite lost. Any idea? Does this kind of triangular tiling exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a quarter of it.

**Upd.** OK, the initial description was probably too terse, so I'll expand it a bit. Define a sequence as $a_1=6$ and $a_{n+1}$ is the greatest possible leg that would form a Pythagorean triangle with $a_n$ for another leg, that is:
$$a_{n+1}=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{a_n^2}4-1, &\text{if $a_n$ is even}\\
\dfrac{a_n^2-1}2, &\text{if $a_n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

Mark the points $a_n$ with odd $n$ on one axis and those with even $n$ on another. Then connect them in a zigzag fashion as follows. (The drawing is not to scale!)

[image: tiling]

I can claim with a good deal of confidence that the sequence never stops and never repeats. The problem is with the other three quarters. Well, maybe we can do them in a similar way, but starting with other Pythagorean triangles.

So it goes.

Comment: (+1) Nice approach. I will think about that.